# C# Generic List constructor gives me a MethodAccessException

Tags: c#, generics

I make a list in my code like so:

```
List<IConnection> connections = new List<IConnection>();
```

where IConnection is my own interface. This is in a .NET 2.0 executable. If I run the code on my machine (with lots of .Net versions installed) it works fine. If I run it on my test machine (which only has .NET 3.5 SP1 installed) then I get a MethodAccessException in the System.Collections.Generic.List constructor. Any ideas what could be going wrong?

Comment: What is the error message? Does it have an inner exception?

Comment: I have no idea. It's an "Unhandled Exception" that fires before my code even starts running.

Comment: Unhandled Exception: System.MethodAccessException: System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor()

Comment: I don't have VS installed on the machine, i guess i'll have to do that

Comment: Are there any code trust issues? strong -names, partial trust ...

Comment: Can you show us your using statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to remove some possibilities - re-build your code by replacing:

```
List<IConnection> connections = new List<IConnection>();
```

with

```
List<int> connections = new List<int>();
```

In other words, it might be helpful to know if the list can be created with a type other then `IConnection`.

I'm not sure where to take it after that, but at least give this a go, to see if you can get your code to run at all.

Comment: oh, duh, one of the DLLs was out of date, thanks for your isolation suggestion, i feel totally dumb :)